# What to do if my question is getting copied 1:1 to another website?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question at Stack Overflow which you can see here [my Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44953747/5111904)

I did some further research and found a website which copied my question 1:1. You can see it here [Website with my question](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/1822659/visual-studio-code-pylint-autofix-not-showing-up-on-ubuntu-1704-ask-question.html).

Is it legal to copy the question without mentioning the source? How should I react to this? Should I just ignore it?